# Angularjs com Guid em Asp.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, html5, angularjs

Estou usando pela primeira vez o AngularJs e gostaria de saber por que isto não é possível, noto que durante o debug, acontece vários erros de Parse dentro do min.js do angular, acredito que seja por que o tipo que estou passando para o controller dele é do tipo Guid. Alguma solução?

```
<script>
    angular.module("tecboxAngular").controller("SetorController",
        function ($scope) {
            $scope.SetarIdParaEdicao = function (itemId) {
                alert(itemId);
                $scope.setorId = itemId;              // The function returns the product of p1 and p2
            }
        });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="table-responsive" ng-model="setorId" ng-controller="SetorController">
        <table class="table table-hover" style="font-size: 11px; font-weight: 500;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>NOME</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @{
    int classAux = 0;
    string classe;

    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (classAux > 0)
        {
            classe = "warning";
            classAux = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            classe = String.Empty;
            classAux++;
        }
        <tr class="@classe" ng-click="SetarIdParaEdicao(@item.Id)">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Nome)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/Setor/Edit/{{setorId}}">Editar</a>
    </div>
}
```

as tags que inicializam o Angularjs estão em outro arquivo, mas tudo esta funcionando, pois o alert dentro do script funciona quando altero o valor que é passado pelo controller.

Answer (score 0):

### Declaração da div

```
<div class="table-responsive" ng-model="setorId" ng-controller="SetorController">
```

### Chamada do controler setando a variável com o Id do item atual.

```
<tr class="@classe" ng-click="SetarIdParaEdicao('@item.Id')">
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.Id)
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Nome)
    </td>
</tr>
```

### Controller

```
<script>
    angular.module("tecboxAngular").controller("SetorController", function ($scope) {
        $scope.GetIdParaEdicao = function (itemId) {
            $scope.setorId = itemId;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Luiz, se a sua resposta respondeu a sua pergunta, você pode marcá-la como *resposta*. Isso ajuda os outros a identificarem que essa pergunta já foi respondida.